# How to get the custom arguments of the custom filter in Vue

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to alert the custom arguments from the custom filter in Vue,
but it cannot be achieved.

Could anyone tell me what's the matter with my coding?

I have tried the following:

```
Vue.filter('toDou',(item,a,b)=>{
   alert(a+','+b);
   return item<10 ? '0' +item : '' +item;
})
var vm = new Vue({
  el:'#app',
  data:{
    a:9
  },
})
```

Here is the HTML

```
<div id="app">
{{a | toDou 1 2}}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit late, but here is a solution.

You should add the `a` and `b` parameters in parenthesis like `{{a | toDou(1,2)}}`. The parameter `a` will be passed into the `item`.